# can't load remote webpage from loadURL() in electron

Tags: electron

```
const {app,BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

function createWindow(){
   let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
   win.loadURL('https://github.com')
   win.on('closed', () => {
   win = null
  })
}
app.on('ready',createWindow)
```

when I run the application, window pop but display blank.

1. how to load remote site in electron?
2. how to send http request to Restful api of server and process response?

Comment: My first thought would be to make `win` a global variable (instead of declaring it inside the function), but then again, your original code is working for me.